# Create hyperlink text with values ​from the database in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to create a hyperlink inside a modal bootstrap. But in my case, I get the value from the database through tag "id" in a tag `H4`.
So, it's like this `<h6 id="account_instagram"></h6>` and it will show the username instagram.

My question is, how to create a hyperlink to go to the user profile on that user's Instagram account?

That is my design modal :

```
<!-- Awal Design Modal -->
  <div id="show_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="background: #000;"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 style="font-size: 24px; color: #17919e; text-shadow: 1px 1px #ccc;"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Student Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 25px"><h6>Nama</h5></td>
                  <td style="width: 25px"><h6> : </h5></td>
                  <td><h6 id="nama"></h6></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h6>Alamat</p></td>
                  <td><h6> : </h5></td>
                  <td><h6 id="alamat"></h6></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h6>Email</h6></td>
                  <td><h6> : </h5></td>
                  <td><h6 id="email"></h6></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h6>Akun IG</h6></td>
                  <td><h6> : </h5></td>
                  <td><h6 id="akun_ig"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h6>Nomor HP</h6></td>
                  <td><h6> : </h5></td>
                  <td><h6 id="nomor_hp"></h6></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 25px"><h6>Berpakaian</h6></td>
                  <td><h6> : </h5></td>
                  <td><h6 id="berpakaian"></h6></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h6>Keahlian</h6></td>
                  <td><h6> : </h5></td>
                  <td><h6 id="keahlian_foto"></h6></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h6>Spesifikasi</h6></td>
                  <td><h6> : </h5></td>
                  <td><h6 id="spesifikasi_foto"></h6></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h6>Kamera</h6></td>
                  <td><h6> : </h5></td>
                  <td><h6 id="kamera"></h6></td>
                </tr>
                <td><h6>Flash</h6></td>
                  <td><h6> : </h5></td>
                <td><h6 id="flash"></h6></td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
<!-- Akhir Design Modal -->
```

This is my javascript modal :

```
<!-- Modal Detail Fotografer -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $('.view_detail').click(function()
          {
            var id = $(this).attr('id'); //get the attribute value  
            $.ajax(
              {
                url : "<?php echo base_url('pencari/get_fg_data')?>",
                data:{id : id},
                method:'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(response)
                  {
                    $('#nama').html(response.nama); //hold the response in id and show on popup
                    $('#email').html(response.email);
                    $('#nomor_hp').html(response.nomor_hp);
                    $('#alamat').html(response.alamat);
                    $('#akun_ig').html(response.akun_ig);
                    $('#keahlian_foto').html(response.keahlian_foto);
                    $('#spesifikasi_foto').html(response.spesifikasi_foto); //hold the response in id and show on popup
                    $('#kamera').html(response.kamera); //hold the response in id and show on popup
                    $('#flash').html(response.flash); //hold the response in id and show on popup
                    $('#berpakaian').html(response.flash); //hold the response in id and show on popup
                    $('#flash').html(response.flash); //hold the response in id and show on popup

                    $('#show_modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: true});
                  }
              });
          });
      });
  </script>
<!-- Akhir Modal Detail Fotografer -->
```

Comment: You're closing `<h6>` with `</h5>` and `</p>` (Suggestion: only use `<h6>` on "_real_" headlines, consider using a CSS style to mimic `<h6>`). `<td><h6>Flash</h6></td>` is missing a `<tr></tr>`. Your question is how to create a link? The basics: `<a href="URLTOGOTO">LINKTEXT</a>`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: It's not really clear what part of this is giving you trouble.

Comment: Just add link like https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME

Comment: but how to make it dynamic link value ?
if i use `<a href="URLTOGOTO">LINKTEXT</a>`, it will static link.

Comment: The username you have import with API instagram or you have a database with username?